# Entity framework constraint to keep the value positive with concurrent calls

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, concurrency

I'm currently making an ASP.NET MVC4 application with Code first Entity framework(5.0). This is my first project with ASP.NET MVC and Entity framework so I'm quite overwhelmed by some of the details. The application deals with transactions in a supermarket by cashiers.

In order to make a sale in the supermarket, I have a list of available products and the available amount for each one. As logic dictates, there shouldn't be negative amount of a given product at any time - so my question is, how can I solve concurrency in the best possible way?

The problem may arise when this happens:

We have 4 bananas available.
Cashier A tries to make a sale for 2 bananas.
Cashier B tries to make a sale with 3 bananas at the same time.
If both transactions make it through, the database is left with -1 bananas and is in an invalid state.

So what is the best way to prevent this? I tried to find several options, but I don't know which one to chose or whether they are well-suited:

1. Add a Rowversion column so that every transaction is made only if no changes have been made to the database. The problem I see here is that there might be many transactions at the same moment and I don't know whether such a harsh check(returning an error every time another cashier made a transaction) is worth it considering that the we only need to keep the amount positive. I.e. there might be only 1-2 transactions a day that cause a problem and the cashiers would have to recheck their sales constantly.
2. Perform a check after every SaveChanges in the transaction and if the amount of items is invalid, rollback.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This constraint is easier to enforce in the database. 2 options that spring to mind are (I'd go with the second one):

1. Do the updates with a stored procedure which can check that the resultant count >= 0
2. Add a column constraint that the column must be >= 0

Comment: The second option seems great, but I couldn't find a way to do it. If savechanges() throws me an exception when the value gets < 0, it'd be perfect.
But how can I add the column constraint using code-first? Range doesn't seem to do anything on database level as a constraint. Must I add it manually and how?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You'll probably find what you need here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621 under Customizing Migrations. Another option is to run some custom DDL to generate the constraint.

Comment: Apparently Code-first does not support Check constraints via Annotations at all at the current time.

So far the only solution I've come up with is the one you proposed: writing the DDL myself in a code-based migration as this:

 Sql("ALTER TABLE CashDesk ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Positive_Money_Amount CHECK (AvailableAmount >= 0)");

Thanks for the assistance!